# How To convert a large table to PDF using flying saucer?

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer, html-to-pdf

I have a html with large number of columns(you can find the sample at this [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/99923120/stackoverflow/test.html))

Now When I try to convert it to PDF using [flying saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/)([jar link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/99923120/flying%20saurcer%20jars.rar) recompiled to work with iText 2.1.X), the [generated PDF](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/99923120/stackoverflow/test.pdf) has truncated Columns

Is there some way to make Flying saucer to either break the table or to increase the width of the page according to the html content?

This is the code that I am using

```
String doc = file.toURI().toURL().toString();
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocument(doc);
String outputFile = "test.pdf";
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Where **file** is the html which I am trying to convert.

Answer (score 2):

Use [YAHP](http://www.allcolor.org/YaHPConverter/) library.This is the best library I have worked so far to convert HTML to PDF. This is written on the top of flying saucer which is a big disappointment as compared to it's popularity.It won't even render simple input text boxes.So, I turned to `YAHP` library which is excellent for your case.

try this code after you get all the jars related to this library.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.allcolor.yahp.converter.CYaHPConverter;
import org.allcolor.yahp.converter.IHtmlToPdfTransformer;
import org.htmlcleaner.CleanerProperties;
import org.htmlcleaner.HtmlCleaner;
import org.htmlcleaner.PrettyHtmlSerializer;
import org.htmlcleaner.TagNode;

public class YahpHtmlToPdf {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            CleanerProperties props = new CleanerProperties();
            props.setTranslateSpecialEntities(true);
            props.setTransResCharsToNCR(true);
            props.setOmitComments(true);
            TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner(props).clean(new File("C:\\Users\\MyComputer\\Desktop\\aspose.html"));
            String newString=new PrettyHtmlSerializer(props).getAsString(tagNode, "ISO-8859-1");
            CYaHPConverter converter = new CYaHPConverter();
            File fout = new File("C:\\sample\\aspose.pdf");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fout);
            Map properties = new HashMap();
            List headerFooterList = new ArrayList();
            properties.put(IHtmlToPdfTransformer.PDF_RENDERER_CLASS,IHtmlToPdfTransformer.FLYINGSAUCER_PDF_RENDERER);
            converter.convertToPdf(newString,IHtmlToPdfTransformer.A1P,headerFooterList, "file:///temp/",out,properties);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

}
```

[image]This is screenshot of pdf generated with your html. .You can specify page size like this `IHtmlToPdfTransformer.A1P`.

Comment: But i will still need to set the page width which i donot knw. Number of columns can be 2,3 or 20. The html is created on the fly

Comment: In the above API you can set the page width and height based on the table size.

Comment: I don't know table size, to know that i will need to parse the html

Answer (score 1):

Its possible to change the pagesize if you know the size you need.

Use the `@page` rule for this:
*Please note: in this example im working on html with [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) (see comment).*

```
/*
 * This part is optional - Jsoup is used for cleaning the html and inserting the style tag into the head.
 * You can use everything else for doing this.
 * 
 * If you will use Jsoup, make shure you set proper charset (2nd parameter).
 * 
 * Note: this is NOT a W3C Document but a Jsoup one.
 */
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file, null);

/*
 * Here you specify the pagesize you need (size: with height).
 * Inserting this html is the key part!
 */
doc.head().append("<style type=\"text/css\"><!--@page { size:50.0cm 20.0cm; }--></style>");


ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

/*
 * This part ist jsoup related. 'doc.toString()' does nothing else than
 * returning the Html of 'doc' as a string.
 * 
 * You can set it like in your code too.
 */
renderer.setDocumentFromString(doc.toString());

final String outputFile = "test.pdf";
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
renderer.layout();
renderer.createPDF(os);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

With this code you'll get a Pdf where the whole table is on a landscape page (maybe you have to change width / height for your needs.

Comment: Hey thanks for answering, but I don't know the size of the page as the content html is generated on the fly, so it can have 2 columns or 20 columns, it all depends on the type of report generated and also the content inside the table cell can increase the width of a column

Comment: I see ... you can check if [page-break settings](http://flyingsaucerproject.github.com/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_37) or [FS extensions](http://flyingsaucerproject.github.com/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_44) can help you here. But i guess it's not possible that FS calculates the pagesize. If all wents bad you have calculate the width of a table by its content (eg. sum up textlengths of all cells and set proper width). The height of the table shouldn't be a problem since you can use `page-break` (see first link) here.